# Join votes table and sum all votes

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got two tables. One of them contains quotes and the other one lists all given votes (either +1 or -1) for each quote. For demonstration purposes I've made simplified versions of the two tables:

### Quotes

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | quote                                                                 |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | If you stare into the Abyss long enough the Abyss stares back at you. |
|  2 | Don't cry because it's over. Smile because it happened.               |
|  3 | Those that fail to learn from history, are doomed to repeat it.       |
|  4 | Find a job you love and you'll never work a day in your life.         |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### Votes

```
+----+-------+------+
| ID | quote | vote |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 |     1 |   -1 |
|  2 |     1 |   -1 |
|  3 |     3 |    1 |
|  4 |     3 |   -1 |
|  5 |     3 |    1 |
|  6 |     3 |   -1 |
|  7 |     4 |    1 |
|  8 |     4 |    1 |
|  9 |     4 |    1 |
+----+-------+------+
```

I'd like to list all quotes on my site and show the respective vote count besides. At first, the SQL query should read all quotes and afterwards join the votes table. However, it should finally list the sum of all votes for each quote. The result of the SQL query will therefore look as follows:

```
+----+-----------------+------+
| ID | quote           | vote |
+----+-----------------+------+
|  1 | If you stare... |   -2 |
|  2 | Don't cry...    | NULL |
|  3 | Those that...   |    0 |
|  4 | Find a job...   |    3 |
+----+-----------------+------+
```

How does the SQL query look like that does the previously described?

Comment: Very nice question and well formated, it's so rare, +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
    `quotes`.`id` as `ID`,
    `quote`.`quote` as `quote`,
    SUM(`votes`.`vote`) AS `vote`
FROM  `quotes`
    LEFT JOIN `votes`
        ON `quotes`.`id` = `votes`.`quote`
GROUP BY `quotes`.`id`
```

should do the trick.

Assuming `id` columns are primary keys (they are unique for each record).

Comment: It's unsafe select ungrouped field `quote`.`quote`. Where is guaranty that its value is unique?

Comment: @triclosan grouping is needed for ANSI compatibility but unoptimal and not needed for mysql. Do you really think the author is stupid enough not having ID unique?

Comment: @Scorpi0: Why additional `GROUP BY`? Please explain your edit.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  ID, quote, (SELECT sum(vote) from votes where votes.quote=quotes.ID)
FROM 
  quotes
```

Comment: Surprisingly easy solution. Is this also the fastest solution regarding performance?

Comment: @Fabianus: It would be harder to find slower solution. This solution uses sub-selects, which is very bad way of doing such a simple thing. The other would be implicit join.

Comment: Definitively a bad idea to subquery like that, -1

Comment: Unless MySQL has an absolutely atrocious optimiser, a correlated sub-query (such as this) should yield the same or similar execution/explain plan as joining on an inline view (sub-query).  Which itself should be similar to the answer from Tadeck.  If MySQL does indeed have such an atrocious optimiser, that correlated sub-queries perform as badly as implied by comments here, could someone please support this with example performance statistics?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT q.id, q.quote, SUM(v.vote ) as summ
FROM Quotes q 
LEFT JOIN Votes v ON q.id=v.quote 
GROUP BY q.id, q.quote                                                                 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.  The left join means the vote summaries are included even if there is no line.

```
select ID, quote, total_votes from quotes
left join 
(select quote, sum(vote) as total_votes from quotes
 group by quote) ) as vote_totals
on quotes.ID = vote_totals.quote
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select q.id, q.quote, sum(v.vote) from
quotes q
inner join votes v on
q.id= v.quote
group by v.quote
```

Comment: If we meed just quotes then eliminate votes from select option

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Quotes.ID ID, Quotes.QUOTE QUOTE, SUM(Votes.vote) VOTE FROM Quotes LEFT JOIN Votes ON Votes.quote = Quotes.id
```