# Tally votes using SQL and JOIN (is this possible?)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, posts

My question is [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611513/join-votes-table-and-sum-all-votes), which I've tried the solution to, but it wasn't exactly right for my scenario.

I have 2 tables: votes and posts. Here is a basic sketch:

```
`posts`
----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | post_title                                                            |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Hello world.                                                          |
|  2 | This is a post!                                                       |
|  3 | What is the meaning of life?                                          |
|  4 | Looking for a good time?                                              |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------

`votes`
+----+---------+
| ID | post_id | 
+----+---------+
|  1 |     1   |  
|  2 |     1   | 
|  3 |     1   |  
|  4 |     3   | 
|  5 |     3   |  
|  6 |     4   |  
+----+---------+
```

**Problem**:

I want to know how many votes each post got, and display them so that the post with the highest vote is at the top.

```
     Post ID   Vote Count
   +---------+-----------+
   | 1       | 3         |
   | 3       | 2         |
   | 4       | 1         |
   | 2       | 0         |
```

What does the SQL query look like to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select post_id, count(*)
from votes
group by post_id
order by count(*) desc
```

EDIT:

```
select v.post_id, count(*)
from votes v INNER JOIN posts p ON v.post_id = p.id
group by v.post_id
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks! (Would it be a lot harder to display the post_title instead of the id?)

Comment: @Ankur just JOIN to posts and add post_title to the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS tally
  FROM votes
 GROUP 
    BY post_id
UNION
SELECT ID AS post_id, 0 AS tally
  FROM posts
 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM votes);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include a Posts with a Zero Vote count without doing a UINON you can do

```
  SELECT 
         p.id, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN v.post_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS tally
  FROM  
      posts p
      LEFT JOIN votes v
      ON v.post_id = p.id
  ORDER BY  
      SUM(CASE WHEN v.postid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
  GROUP 
    BY p.id
```

SUM/CASE is required here because COUNT(NULL) = 1

Since your structure is so close here's [an example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2027/sample-for-7982283) you can look at on data.SE